# Use SQL Server Compact with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, asp.net-identity

I'm using the latest ASP.NET MVC, Identity and Entity Framework.

The [sample Identity project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1) uses Sql Server Express. I want to use Sql Server Compact.

What I did:

- Created a new empty solution (not MVC template)
- Installed sample project: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre`
- Installed: `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact`
- Installed: `Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact`
- Changed default connection string in `web.config` to:

  ```
  <add name="Foo" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
       connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Foo.sdf;" />
  ```
- Changed `ApplicationDbContext` to use the `Foo` connection string:

  ```
  ApplicationDbContext() : base("name=Foo", false)
  ```

Problem is, when `ApplicationDbContext` is accessed for the first time (during seeding, in the `ApplicationDbInitializer.InitializeIdentityForEF()` method):

- the database is created
- I get an `InvalidOperationException: UserId not found` for the line `result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);`

I thought it would be as simple as changing the connection string - so what am I doing wrong? Or put differently, *how do I convert the solution from SQL Server Express to SQL Server Compact?*

Comment: I've followed your instructions and everything works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the error. My connection string was wrong, I had:

```
<add name="Foo"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
     connectionString="
       Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Foo.sdf;
       Persist Security Info=false;
       "/>
```

which doesn't work (XML, so thought whitespace is ignored, it's not), whereas this does:

```
<add name="Foo"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Foo.sdf;Persist Security Info=false;" />
```

Regardless, the question itself contains a step-by-step for using sqlce with Identity2. Maybe it'll help someone.